# pybig Module on python

Tags: python, extract

.big files are known as EAgames archives.

Big files can be extracted internally through the xcc mixer program, but I am writing a code to extract them through Python.

I installed Python 3.11.3 and pybig module 1.0.5, but the module was not imported.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users{UserName}\Desktop\python\TEST3\TEST big file extractor.py", line 1, in 
from pybig import BigFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybig'

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this module https://pypi.org/project/pyBIG/ then you need to case the module name properly. Might be worth checking out the examples:

```py
from pyBIG import Archive
```